# Extracting the lower and upper bounds of Forecast and Appending to a dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, append

I have a dataframe with forecasted values for a particular ID group. I am able to extract them using `purchaseforecast$lower` and `purchaseforecast$upper` but not able to append them to the empty data frame I have created below. I would also like to add the id from the loop into the empty data frame. Any help is appreciated.

Empty data frame:

```
finaloutput <- data.frame(id =integer,
                 lowerlimit=integer(length = 0L),
                 upperlimit=integer(length = 0L))
```

Forecasted data frame:

```
purchaseforecastmn <- forecast.HoltWinters(object = daily_seasonality, level = 95, h =30)
```

Values I would like to append to lower limit is `purchaseforecastmn$lower` and upper limit is `purchaseforecastmn$upper` in addition to an id value from the loop.

Sample code:

```
dailyseasonality1 <- c(1:365)

dailyseasonality2 <- HoltWinters(dailyseasonality1, gamma = FALSE,beta = FALSE)

purchaseforecastmn <- forecast.HoltWinters(object = dailyseasonality2, level = 95, h =30)
```

Comment: Consider adding a small example data set and code that runs.

Comment: Added the example dataset under Sample code Mark. I would like to append values of purchaseforecastmn$lower to lowerlimit, purchaseforecastmn$upper to upperlimit and "1" to id. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question, but the code below returns a `data.frame` containing everything in `purchaseforecastmn` plus an `id` variable:

```
# install.packages('forecast')

library(forecast)

n.ids <- 30

id <- 1:n.ids

dailyseasonality1 <- c(1:365)
dailyseasonality2 <- HoltWinters(dailyseasonality1, gamma = FALSE,beta = FALSE)
purchaseforecastmn <- forecast.HoltWinters(object = dailyseasonality2, level = 95, h = n.ids)
purchaseforecastmn

my.data <- as.data.frame(purchaseforecastmn)
my.data <- data.frame(id, my.data)
```

Here is the output `data.frame my.data`:

```
    id Point.Forecast    Lo.95 Hi.95
366  1       364.9999 364.9999   365
367  2       364.9999 364.9999   365
368  3       364.9999 364.9999   365
369  4       364.9999 364.9999   365
370  5       364.9999 364.9999   365
371  6       364.9999 364.9999   365
372  7       364.9999 364.9999   365
373  8       364.9999 364.9999   365
374  9       364.9999 364.9999   365
375 10       364.9999 364.9999   365
376 11       364.9999 364.9999   365
377 12       364.9999 364.9999   365
378 13       364.9999 364.9999   365
379 14       364.9999 364.9999   365
380 15       364.9999 364.9999   365
381 16       364.9999 364.9999   365
382 17       364.9999 364.9999   365
383 18       364.9999 364.9999   365
384 19       364.9999 364.9999   365
385 20       364.9999 364.9999   365
386 21       364.9999 364.9999   365
387 22       364.9999 364.9999   365
388 23       364.9999 364.9999   365
389 24       364.9999 364.9999   365
390 25       364.9999 364.9999   365
391 26       364.9999 364.9999   365
392 27       364.9999 364.9999   365
393 28       364.9999 364.9999   365
394 29       364.9999 364.9999   365
395 30       364.9999 364.9999   365
```

If you just want the first row of `my.data`, you can extract it with:

```
my.output <- my.data[1,]
```

Regarding a loop, I guess I would need to see an example with code that runs.  This might work.

```
library(forecast)

n.iters <- 30

my.output <- matrix(NA, ncol = 4, nrow = n.iters)

for(i in 1:n.iters) {

     dailyseasonality1 <- c(1:365)
     dailyseasonality2 <- HoltWinters(dailyseasonality1, gamma = FALSE,beta = FALSE)
     purchaseforecastmn <- forecast.HoltWinters(object = dailyseasonality2, level = 95, h = 30)
     my.data <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(purchaseforecastmn))

     my.output[i,1] <- i
     my.output[i,2:4] <- my.data[1,1:3]

}

colnames(my.output) <- c('id', 'Point.Forecast', 'Lo.95', 'Hi.95')
my.output
```